# php put multidimentional arrays into one big list from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to create a single array of status id's and their names pulled from the database.  My array needs to come out looking like this

```
 $options = array("1" => "Active", "2" => "Inactive");
```

I've been trying to use array_push and array merge but it keeps going wrong.  Here is what I have so far...

```
 $allStatus = implode(',', array('1', '2'));
 $statuses = $clCont->getAllRecords('*', '`status` WHERE idstatus IN ('.$allStatus.')');
 $status = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statuses);


 $statusOpt = array();
 do 
 {  
    array_push($statusOpt[$status['idstatus']],$status['statusName']);
 }  
 while ($status = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statuses));

 $rows = mysqli_num_rows($statuses);

 if($rows > 0) 
 {
  mysqli_data_seek($statuses, 0);
  $status = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statuses);
 }

print_r($statusOpt);
```

Comment: So what is the result you get?

Comment: I seem to be getting a blank array    Array
(
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)

Comment: ah ok so I'm getting the ID in there just not the field name.  I've checked this over and the field name is there and being selected its just not putting it into the array

Comment: I'm also gettting this message Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's try to modify your code:

```
 $allStatus = implode(',', array('1', '2'));
 $statuses = $clCont->getAllRecords('*', '`status` WHERE idstatus IN ('.$allStatus.')');
 // you don't need to fetch first item.
 // $status = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statuses);
 // and use a do-while loop
 // use just while:

 $statusOpt = array();
 while ($status = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statuses)) 
 {
     $id = $status['idstatus'];
     // The first time you try to put a value in a 
     // $statusOpt[$status['idstatus']] it's not exists, 
     // so you should define it explicitly:
     if (!isset($statusOpt[$id])) {
         $statusOpt[$id] = array();
     }

     // after that it should be okay:
     array_push($statusOpt[$id],$status['statusName']);
 }  

 print_r($statusOpt);
```

Comment: thank you very much. I need to use this all over my new project.  You've been a massive help.  All works perfectly